# Modal from Dropdown link in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to have a modal launch from a link that is in my dropdown menu. The modal seems to launch (the site goes grey) but it can't be seen. Modals from regular links not in the dropdown work just fine. I have fooled with the jquery but nothing has worked out since I am new to jquery. Here is my site code.

```
<nav class="pull-right">
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Item<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <div id="DeleteItem" class="modal hide fade">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a data-dismiss="modal" class="close">×</a>

                    <h3>Delete My Item?</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you really want to delete My Item?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" class="btn btn-primary" href="/items/myitem">Delete
                        Item</a>
                    <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" href="#">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Delete Item Modal -->
            <li><a href="/items/myitem/edit">Edit Item</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteItem" href="/items/myitem">Delete Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here are the javascript files at the end of the

```
<!-- Javascript placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is my rails code just in case.

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><%= @item.name %><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <%= render "items/delete" %><!-- Delete Item Modal -->
              <li><%= link_to 'Edit Item', edit_item_path(@item) %></li>
              <li><%= link_to 'Delete Item', @item,
                              "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#DeleteItem" %></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    <div class="modal hide fade" id="DeleteItem">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <%= content_tag :h3, "Delete #{@item.name}" + "?" %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= content_tag :p, "Are you sure you really want to delete #{@item.name}" + "?" %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= link_to 'Delete Item', @item, method: :delete, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you may be running into a problem by including the modal div element within the navbar structure.  My intuition is that you should include it somewhere near the end of your markup.

Comment: That was it! Thanks! I was just going off the docs, they placed the modal div right above the link to it.

Comment: @cooldman224 can you update the answer with what worked? Its a bit ambiguous ~at the end of markup~.