# Twitter Bootstrap - Add 'backdrop' to dropdown jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not good at jQuery, so I came here for help. I want to know how to add the Modal backdrop to Dropdown's that is in Twitter Bootstrap?

The jQuery(s)

Modal - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js

Dropdown - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js

Thanks.

Comment: are you referring to something like this? _http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510003/modal-from-dropdown-link-in-twitter-bootstrap_

Comment: I think so. But without a preview, I'm not entirely sure.